# Audio loaded dynamically from array does not play

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

Click should load an .mp3 from an array of .mp3s and play it. The error is: "does not support method play." Where is the mistake? Thank you.

```
$("<audio/>").attr("src", "audio/" + main_sounds[i]).load().play();
```

Comment: `load()` does not have a `play()` function.

Comment: Do I not have to load the audio before playing? Can't I concatenate load and play?

Comment: Yes you can, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `$('audio')` doesn't have the play function.
Try `$("<audio/>").attr("src", "audio/" + main_sounds[i]).load().get(0).play();`